# React Date Time Picker Date object not storing to Firebase real time database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```js
const dataToPush = {
  firstName: seniorfirstName,
  lastName: seniorlastName,
  familyMember: userid,
  birthdate: date
}
var k = dbSeniors.push(dataToPush);
```

In this code, I'm basically trying to store a date which has been declared like:

```js
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
```

And:

```js
const [date, setDate]=useState(new Date());
```

Moreover, whenever I print to console, then date is indeed what I choose, in this case:

> Wed Mar 11 2020 22:13:56 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time).

However, whenever I go to firebase than the date key, value pair has not been pushed at all! 
Also, when I tried converting the Date object toString using the `toString(date)` function, I just got "[object Undefined]".

Comment: "I tried converting the Date object toString using the `toString(date)` function". To convert an object to a string, you call `toString()` on that object. So `date.toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use the toString in the wrong way, you should use it like this :

```
date.toString()
```

instead of toString(date)

The other solution is to store the date as a timestamp in firebase :

```
firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(date).toDate());
```